# how to add mysql_real_escape_string() in this code

Tags: mysql-real-escape-string

$id = $_GET['id'];

```
$getfile = $db->query('select * from file where id = '.$id, database::GET_ROW);
$folq = $db->query("select id as pid,folder,name as catname,name,thumb,pathc from category where id = ".$parentid, database::GET_ROW);
```

when i used mysql_real_escape_string()  it get error message on my web site

Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ' line 1

Comment: There should be NO mysql_real_escape_string() in this code

Answer (score -1):

before running the database queries perform mysql_real_escape_string on the inputs:

```
$id = mysql_real_escape_string($id);
$parentid = mysql_real_escape_string($parentid);
$getfile = $db->query('select * from file where id = '.$id, database::GET_ROW);
$folq = $db->query("select id as pid,folder,name as catname,name,thumb,pathc from category where id = ".$parentid, database::GET_ROW);
```

Comment: can you paste the query string that is working fine?

Comment: I think the issue is not with mysql_real_escape_string... echo the value of $id... it should not get blank value.

Comment: Downvoting any question or answer without providing reason is NOT a good gesture. If you (whoever downvoted this) are downvoting any question or answer, please provide proper justification so that I can improve myself.

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'order by rand() limit 3' at line 1

Comment: include 'includes/config.php';
 include 'header.php';

 $id = $_GET['id'];
   
 $getfile = $db->query('select * from file where id = '.$id, database::GET_ROW);
 $folq = $db->query("select id as pid,folder,name as catname,name,thumb,pathc from category where id = ".$parentid, database::GET_ROW);

Comment: the code block you pasted doesn't have "order by rand() limit 3" ... echo $id before passing it to the query... is there any other code related to it?